# Mapping variables to key value pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, key-value

I have a key value pair assigned as `` that I would like to access by matching to a separate variable.

```
var dict = []; 

dict.push({
    key:   "shelter",
    value: "icon1"
});

dict.push({
    key:   "legal",
    value: "icon2"
});


dict.push({
    key:   "bar",
    value: "icon3"
});
```

For example, if I had feature collection below, I would want `symbol` to match `dict.value` and then `dict.key` to be logged to the console.  So, in this case it would the log would be `"icon1", "icon2", "icon3"`

```
var places = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "shelter"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.038659, 38.931567]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "legal"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.003168, 38.894651]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "bar"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.090372, 38.881189]
        }

    }]
};


places.features.forEach(function(feature) {
    var symbol = feature.properties['icon'];

console.log(dict.value)

});
```

How would one write this in javascript ?

Comment: `dict` is not a good name to choose for an `[]`

Comment: your dict is basically a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Then you could just use `dict.get(symbol)` or replace that array with a simple object and just do `dict[symbol]`

Comment: Why do you call your key, `key` and value, `value`?  Why not use them as they're described (e.g., `{ shelter:'icon', legal:'icon2', ...}`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object as dictionary for the wanted key value pairs. Then take the value of the iteration as key for the dictionary.

```js
var dict = { shelter: "icon1", legal: "icon2", bar: "icon3" },
    places = { type: "FeatureCollection", features: [{ type: "Feature", properties: { icon: "shelter" }, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-77.038659, 38.931567] } }, { type: "Feature", properties: { icon: "legal" }, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-77.003168, 38.894651] } }, { type: "Feature", properties: { icon: "bar" }, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-77.090372, 38.881189] } }] };

places.features.forEach(function (feature) {
    var symbol = feature.properties.icon;
    console.log(dict[symbol]);
});
```